# What is the advantage of FTP Active Mode Transmission?

Tags: sockets, networking, ftp, rfc

FTP [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#page-44) specifies that the data connection is opened by the server from port 20 (default) to a random port in the client and known by the server through a PORT h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2 command. This is called Active Mode Transmission.

Why should the Server initiate the connection to the client ? **What are the obvious advantages of doing so?** Isn't it better for the Server to be sitting there, listening on the Port 20, waiting for any incoming connections?

Think about a HTTP server with Port 80 open. It is always the client initiating the connection.

Comment: Today, there is no real advantage. It's just a really old protocol from before we discovered how TCP likes to work.

Comment: @user253751 is right. Though this is not a programming question. Please move it to [su] or [networkengineering.se] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).